# RPG tabletop for newbies - ModernWorld

Tags: game-recommendation, modern

I'd like to master my first RPG with all other players being newbies... 
I would like to find a game that can be set in our own city to make it more immersive to them. And maybe a game where the world is close to the actual modern world (at least at the beginning and that could slowly evolve  to something more fantasy/fantastic/scifi).

As I am new to this, I would love to find a book that would help me a lot!

Thank you very much, A

Comment: Are you asking for RPG recommendations? Because [those are considered "off-topic"/inappropriate here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5747/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic-revisited).

Comment: Hi! I used to do a lot of recommending here, back in the day. Maybe try https://www.reddit.com/r/rpg/ where I do a lot now? But also - do a quick search before posting, we get asked a lot of similar questions all the time. (Which is why these questions are OT here. When you've picked a game, this is *the* place for expert answers on the rules of that game!

Comment: thanks a lot for your advises, I m going to manage something :D
I'm going to come back here for more precise questions about particular games. 
Maybe going to try Urban Shadows,  thanks again